# How to find rank of a product of two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are $ 3 \times 3$ real matrices such that $ \text{rank}(AB)=1$ , then $ \text{rank}(BA)$ cannot be??

a. $\ 0$
b. $\ 2$
c. $\ 1$
d. $\ 3$

As far I got into my thoughts is that since rank of product is $1$...
Both matrices have unit rank individually. Also, since this is a $ 3 \times 3$ matrix and rank is less than $3$ implies that the determinant of both would have zero. That indicates that rank cannot be equal to $3$.

But I am not very clear in my head whether my approach is right!!

Comment: "determinant of both would have to be zero" ... that's wrong. It says that $det(AB) = 0$, which in turn says that $det(A) det(B) = 0$. But for a product of two numbers to be zero, they need not both be zero. Consider $2 \cdot 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is almost correct but you cannot deduce the rank of **both** matrices.

Since  rank$(AB)=1$ the determinant of $AB$ is zero and so the determinant of at least **one** of $A$ and $B$ is zero. Therefore the determinant of $BA$ is also zero and so $BA$ cannot be of rank 3.

Comment: @S.Dolan..o yes! Got it. Thankyou.